# Is there a problem if i put a condicitional if with printf and scanf in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

I'm having this code, it's like a calculator of some operators, but it only works until the conditional starts, anyone knows the mistake there?
I know it is in spanish, so i'm trying to calculate the distance between two points, but my main question is what happens when i have a conditional if with more than a printf, it just doesn't work that way, can someone explain me? thanks a lot

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float n, PO, x1, x2, y1, y2, i, POO;
    printf("Esta es la calculadora de lugar geometrico, por favor ingresa una cordenada con un espacio entre x y y ");
    scanf("%f %f", &x1, &y1);
    printf("Ahora, presione 1 si el otro numero será una coordenada,2 si es un numero positivo y negativo, y 3 si hablamos de una recta ");
    scanf("%f", n);
    if (n == 1)
    {
        printf("Ingresa la coordenada de la misma forma que la anterior");
        scanf("%f %f", &x2, &y2);
        printf("Ahora vamos a calcular la distancia entre cada uno de los puntos, junto con un punto P(x,y)");
        PO = sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
        printf("La distancia entre los puntos indicados es %f", PO);
    }
    if (n == 2)
    {
        printf("Ingresa la coordenada de la misma forma que la anterior");
        scanf("%f %f", &x2, &y2);
        printf("Ahora ingresa el numero con su valor absoluto: ");
        scanf("%f", i);
        printf("Ahora vamos a calcular la distancia entre cada uno de los puntos, junto con un punto P(x,y)");
        PO = sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1) - i);
        printf("La distancia entre los puntos indicados (usando su valor positivo) es %f", PO);
        POO = sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1) - i);
        printf("La distancia entre los puntos indicados (usando su valor negativo) es %f", POO);
    }
    if (n == 3)
    {
        printf("Ingresa la coordenada de la misma forma de la anterior");
        scanf("%f", &x2, &y2);
        printf("Ahora vamos a calcular la distancia entre cada uno de los puntos, junto con un punto P(x,y)");
        PO = sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) - abs((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
        printf("La distancia entre los puntos indicados es %f", PO);
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you probably meant `scanf("%f", &n);` (must be address of `n`). Same thing later with `i`.

Comment: thank you, do you know if i take off the syntax, the program can use an if using multiple lines? i know its a simple question, but i alwaysget stuck with any program using that

Comment: I would like to suggest you use `else` with your `if`s. `if (n == 1) { ... } else if (n == 2) { ... }`  There is no reason `n` could not be modified during one of those conditionals so that the following conditionals run, and I'm assuming this is not your intention.

Comment: Also, i did correct that thing and it still doesn't work, do you know what else can i do?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific than "doesn't work". What are you using for input? What to do you expect the result to be? What result are you getting?

Comment: This doesn't make sense either: `scanf("%f", &x2, &y2);` Note there are *two* target arguments provided for *one* actual scan format.

Comment: `abs()` is an `int` function.  Perhaps you want `PO = sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) - fabs((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));`?  Tip: enable all compiler warnings to save time.  Faster and more productive than posting on SO.

Answer (score -4):

You can't compare a float value with an integer value. For internal rappresentation It can generate invalid result. For buffer problem can you use fgets and convert string in type?

Comment: Well, I'm a new C programmer and i'm only using it for school so i don't get what you say; so, i have to change the line 5 to int n,PO, x1, x2,y1, y2, i, POO;  ?

Comment: Yes, you can compare float values with integers *if* you know what you are doing. And since `float` can represent small integers exactly, it would work in this case. But I agree that it is unclean code. When working with integers, one should not use floats

Comment: @JuanitaSaavedra, only `n` should be `int`, the rest can stay `float`, or even better, `double`.

Comment: similarly, it's often helpful when learning to create a function yourself to do comparisons by subtracting 'em off and checking for a range of accuracy! Do also see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for some helpful/dire warnings about floating point math

Comment: Yes. Use same type for compare.

Comment: This answer is a bit too brief IMO. Could you add _why_ this is not a good idea? Any exceptions? What is the "buffer problem" and why does the proposed solution resolve it? Can you give a code example? Are there any references you can cite?